# finding subsets which meets conditions

Tags: circuit-construction, quantum-walks

I have a set `S = {a, b, c, d, e, f}` from which I need to find out if there exists two subsets `S0` and `S1` such that the sum of elements of S0 = sum of elements of S1. Also, the max of `S0` and `S1` cannot exceed `h`. I'm thinking of treating it as a search problem. I have to use quantum walk algorithm to solve and develop the quantum circuit for this as well. I understand that I can encode a to f using qubits for example, then create a circuit for finding sets of possible elements. And another circuit to identify those which meets the criteria. Where to begin? Any references could be of great help.

Comment: Can you give some context that would explain why you posted this question on the quantum computing stackexchange? E.g. does the task require you to use a quantum circuit?

Comment: @RajivKrishnakumar yes, have to create the quantum circuit which does this. added context. thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, what prevents you from using $S_0=S_1$? Do you also have the condition that $S_0\cap S_1=\varnothing$?

Comment: If you have $S_0 \cup S_1 = S$ this would be the subset-sum problem. Should I assume you are looking for smaller-sized solutions?

Comment: @rhundt that's correct. for example, S={0,2,3,4,5,6} then S0= {0,2,3,5} and S1={4,6}. Yes to smaller-sized solutions. Interested to know what approaches to follow.

Comment: @TristanNemoz let's go with no common elements between S0 and S1. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've put an implementation [here](https://github.com/qcc4cp/qcc/blob/main/src/subset_sum.py). The idea is to construct a Hamiltonian, which would be a diagonal matrix, and then use a variational algorithm to see whether there exists a state with eigenvalue 0, which would indicate equilibrium. Of course, since I constructed the Hamiltonian I can just inspect it. VQE-by-peek-a-boo.

This doesn't tell you what the solution is, only whether one exists. At least, at this point. Not sure this could be massaged further to find an exact solution.